# How can I show that an expectation commutes with a $\min$ in this case?

Tags: optimization, expected-value

In slide 14 of [these lecture notes](https://berkeley-me233.github.io/static/ME233_Sp16_L8_LQG.pdf), I found the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a random vector and let $u \in \underline{u}$ denote the constraint that $u$ is a function of $X$. Also assume that there exists $u^o(x)$ such that, $$\min_u f(x,u) = f(x,u^o(x)),\forall x$$ Then, $$\min_{u \in \underline{u}} E[f(X,u)] = E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right]$$

To prove this theorem, the author shows that $$\min_{u \in \underline{u}} E[f(X,u)] \leq E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right]$$ and $$\min_{u \in \underline{u}} E[f(X,u)] \geq E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right]$$ However, I have a question about one of these proofs. According to these lecture notes, here is the proof that $$\min_{u \in \underline{u}} E[f(X,u)] \leq E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right]$$ Let $u^o(x)$ minimize $f(x,u)$. Then,
\begin{align}
\min_u f(x,u) &= f(x,u^o(x)),\forall x \\
\min_u f(X,u) &= f(X,u^o(X)) \\
E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] &= E\left[f(X,u^o(X))\right] \tag{1} \label{q1eq1}\\
&\geq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} E[f(X,u)] \tag{2} \label{q1eq2}
\end{align}
where the author states that they went from \eqref{q1eq1} to \eqref{q1eq2} "because $u^o \in \underline{u}$".

**Question: I am not sure what the author means by "because $u^o \in \underline{u}$" to go from \eqref{q1eq1} to \eqref{q1eq2}. Why didn't the author instead write (notice the constraint under the $\min$ changing compared to \eqref{q1eq2}) $$\begin{align}E\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] &= E\left[f(X,u^o(X))\right] \\
&\geq \min_{u} E[f(X,u)] \end{align}$$**

Comment: Have you tested whether Jenson's Inequality holds?

Comment: @JamieAlizadeh could you elaborate on how it relates here?

Comment: Sorry, you actually don't need Jenson's Inequality. $E[f\left(X, u\right)]$ is just a function that maps elements of $\underline{u}$  to $\mathbb{R}$, so for an arbitrary $u^o \in \underline{u},$ you must have that $E\left[f(X,u^o)\right] \geq \min_{u} E[f(X,u)] $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the following three technical conditions are required for the proofs in this answer to work:

1. The expectation $E[f(X,u)]$ must exist for each $u$ (which can be established by showing that $f$ is measurable in $X$ for each $u$).
2. In addition to condition 1, $\min_u E[f(X,u)]$ must also exist.
3. $\min_u f(x,u)$ must exist for each $x$ (which can be established by showing that $f$ is continuous in $u$ for each $x$).

These conditions ensure that both $\min_u E[f(X,u)]$ and $E[\min_u f(X,u)]$ in the equality in question exist. As long as these conditions are satisfied, then the following proofs in this answer are valid. For details on how to check these conditions, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/108007/311484).

---

**Edit**

It turns out that this theorem is a variation of Lemma 3.1 in section 3, chapter 8, of the book *Introduction to Stochastic Control Theory* by Karl J. Astrom (1970). Its proof can also be found in the same place in the book.

---

Using @JamieAlizadeh's idea in the comments that

> $E[f(X,u)]$ is just a function that maps elements of $\underline{u}$ to $\mathbb R$, so for an arbitrary $u^o \in \underline{u}$, you must have that $$E\left[f(X,u^o)\right] \geq \min_{u} E[f(X,u)]$$

here is an expansion of the proof with some commentary. Suppose that $u^o(x)$ minimizes $f(x,u)$. This would mean that, for every $x$, $$\min_u f(x,u) = f(x,u^o(x))$$ Let $X$ be a random vector. Then, $$\min_u f(X,u) = f(X,u^o(X))$$ This is because every realization of $X$ will satisfy this equality. Next, we can compute the expectation of both sides of this equality with respect to $X$ to get $$E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] = E_X[f(X,u^o(X))]$$ Now let $$g(u) = E_X[f(X,u(X))]$$ Note that the $u$ appearing in $g(u)$ is a function of $X$, such that the function $g$ maps elements of $\underline{u}$, the set of functions $u$ that are a function of $X$, to a real number. We can see that the equality above becomes $$E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] = g\left(u^o\right)$$ Then, by definition,
\begin{align}
g\left(u^o\right) &\geq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} g(u) \\
&= \min_{u \in \underline{u}} E_X[f(X,u(X))]
\end{align}
which completes the proof that $$E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] \geq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} E_X[f(X,u(X))]$$ when $u^o(x)$ minimizes $f(x,u)$.

---

For convenience, here is some commentary on the second part of the proof of the theorem. Namely, the proof that
$$
E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] \leq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} E_X[f(X,u(X))]
$$
Let $v \in \underline{u}$, which means that $v$ is a function of the random vector $X$. Then, for every $x$,
$$
\min_u f(x,u) \leq f(x,v(x))
$$
Because this inequality is true regardless of the value of $x$, then we can say that
$$
\min_u f(X,u) \leq f(X,v(X))
$$
We then take expectations of both sides of this inequality with respect to $X$ (which is a [monotone operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)) to get
$$
E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] \leq E_X\left[f(X,v(X))\right]
$$
As before, let $g(u) = E_X[f(X,u(X))]$, such the inequality above becomes
$$
E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] \leq g(v)
$$
Additionally, note that the left-hand side of this inequality is a constant. Therefore, let $c = E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right]$. The inequality above then reduces to
$$
c \leq g(v)
$$
This inequality states that the constant $c$ on the left-hand side is always less than or equal to $g(v)$, regardless of the function $v \in \underline{u}$. Therefore, if we choose $u$ to be from the set $\underline{u}$, and to minimize $g(u)$ from this set, then the inequality above does not change, which leads to
$$
c \leq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} g(u)
$$
Replacing $c$ and $g(u)$ with their respective definitions leads to
$$
E_X\left[\min_u f(X,u)\right] \leq \min_{u \in \underline{u}} E_X[f(X,u(X))]
$$
which completes the proof of the theorem.

Intuitively, what this theorem is stating is that, given that $$\min_u f(x,u)$$ exists, then the minimization of $E_X[f(X,u)]$ with respect to all functions $u$ that are restricted to be a function of the random vector $X$ is equivalent to the minimization of $f(X,u)$ with respect to all functions $u$ averaged over all possible $X$.

---

For a more general theorem, see:

1. https://mathoverflow.net/a/108007/311484
2. https://mathoverflow.net/a/316540/311484
3. https://mathoverflow.net/a/245303/311484